# No me centra el contenido del navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo una media querie para móvil que me pone el navbar abajo y me cambia el texto por los iconos que es lo que quiero, pero me pasa que cuando es formato móvil me pone todo a la izquierda, he intentado centrarlo con un navbar-center y lo que pasa es que se sale de la pantalla o directamente no lo hace:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="abajo navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
      <a class="navbar-brand eliminar" href="#heading">K. Anthony</a>
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="desktop-nav" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#welcome">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#projects">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about-me">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="mobile-nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center  ">
        <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#welcome"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="sr-only">View Welcome Section</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#portfolio"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-photo-o"></i><span class="sr-only">View Portfolio Section</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#about-me"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-book"></i><span class="sr-only">View About Section</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="sr-only">View Contact Section</span></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Aquí dejo el código restante CSS ya que quizás algunas sugerencias no me van porque algo que lo solapa y que yo no me este dando cuenta:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #0471a6;
}

#navbar a:hover,
#navbar a:focus {
  color: #d81159;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#navbar a.navbar-brand {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-nav {
  flex: 0 2 500px;
}

#desktop-nav {
  display: none;
}

#mobile-nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 603px) {
    #mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  } 

    #desktop-nav {
    display: flex;
  }  

}
```

La querie que me elimina el titulo y me pone a bajo el navbar:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .abajo{
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1030;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .eliminar{
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-center {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    
  }
```

Un imagen para que veáis a lo que me refiero, solamente quiero centrarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tienes #navbar  como **flex**, agrega en tu querie lo siguiente:

```
#navbar {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Esto centra todo el contenido que esté dentro de un contenedor con `display: flex`

Comment: lo he probado y sigue sin centrármelo, no se porque, he quitado el navbar-center que hacia desaparecer el navbar cuando se redimensionaba en móvil y nada.

Comment: @Wail Qué versión de font awesome y bootstrap estás usando?

Comment: De bootstrap uso la versión 4.5.2 y de fontawesome la 5.8.1

Comment: He añadido también la querie que me cambia el texto por los iconos por si es la que perjudica el hacer el centrado

Comment: @Wail puedes colocar una captura del diseño? es que no logro enteder como quedaría con tu código, ya que al reproducirlo en móvil se queda fixed al final el nav y no se visualizan los íconos?

Comment: Claro que te lo va a ocultar al redimensionar la pantalla porque le estas sobreponiendo un valor fuera de pantalla, haz algo, con lo mismo que te mando Elboy> en tu clase .abajo, agregale un margin-bottom de 100px con !important y dinos que es lo que recibes.

Answer (score 1):

por lo que logre entender, creo que el código que dejo te servirá (cambie el segundo icono, ya que no lograba verlo, probablemente por la versión de font awesome)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .navbar-nav {
        flex: 0 2 500px;
    }
    
    #mobile-nav {
        display: flex;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .nav-item {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
        #mobile-nav {
            display: none;
        }
        #desktop-nav {
            display: flex;
        }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        #desktop-nav {
            display: none;
        }
        .abajo {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1030;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .eliminar {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #mobile-nav {
            list-style: none;
        }
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-

awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navbar" class="abajo navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand eliminar" href="#heading">K. Anthony</a>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul id="desktop-nav" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#welcome">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#projects">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about-me">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="mobile-nav" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" style="">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#welcome"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="sr-only">View Welcome Section</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#portfolio"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-car"></i><span class="sr-only">View Portfolio Section</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about-me"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-book"></i><span class="sr-only">View About Section</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="sr-only">View Contact Section</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```